# php / mysql how to delete fields with same name from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-delete

Hi I am building my first website and need a statement to delete any records from 2 tables which contain a Patient_ID that the user specifies:

I have tried

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM appointment 
  WHERE Patient_ID='$patid'
  UNION
  DELETE FROM patient 
  WHERE Patient_ID='$patid'");
```

and also

```
  mysql_query("DELETE FROM appointment INNER JOIN patient 
  WHERE Patient_ID='$patid'");
```

would really appreciate some help with this!

thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just run two separate DELETE commands?

Comment: This is where cascading foreign keys is such a wonderful feature of a relational database

Comment: If you do use two separate delete statements, make sure you're wrapping them in a transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do in one query:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM appointment, patient USING patient INNER JOIN appointment ON (patient.patient_id = appointment.patient_id) WHERE patient.patient_id = '" . intval($patid) . "'";
```

However, in order to maintain data integrity, the best option here would be to define a foreign key constraint on your `appointment` table which references your `patient` table and contains an `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause.

Comment: This seemed the only solution I could comprehend with my basic knowledge... and it worked, thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather do a `StoredProcedure` for the two *delete* statements.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE DeletePatient(IN PatientID INT)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM appointment WHERE Patient_ID = PatientID;
    DELETE FROM patient WHERE Patient_ID = PatientID;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

and on your php script,

```
mysql_query("CALL DeletePatient($patid)");
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

easy

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM appointment WHERE Patient_ID='$patid'");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM patient WHERE Patient_ID='$patid'");
```

don't forget to format your $patid first:

```
$patid = mysql_real_escape_string($patid);
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

As Mark Baker pointed out in an above statement, the best way is if foreign keys are defined properly on the table. Assuming that they are not, however, they should be wrapped into a transaction.

```
$query1 = "DELETE FROM appointment WHERE Patient_ID='".intval($patid)."'";
$query2 = "DELETE FROM patient WHERE Patient_ID='".intval($patid)."'";

mysql_query("START TRANSACTION", $yourConnection); 
mysql_query("BEGIN", $yourConnection); 
mysql_query($query1, $yourConnection); 
mysql_query($query2, $yourConnection); 
mysql_query("COMMIT", $yourConnection);
```

Original Answer:

The only way to do this is to run two separate DELETE commands.

```
$query1 = "DELETE FROM appointment WHERE Patient_ID='".intval($patid)."'";
$query2 = "DELETE FROM patient WHERE Patient_ID='".intval($patid)."'";
```

Comment: It isn't the only way to do it... a single delete can be cascaded through foreign key relationships by MySQL itself

Comment: @MarkBaker - True, however I think more would have to be defined about the asker's tables and intentions. For example, the user may not want to always cascade deletes

Comment: OP should really be defining his tables properly in the first place, with foreign key constraints... even if they don't use cascading deletes